# Counting non zeros in only 1 column of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a Numpy array that is created as follows

```
data=np.zeros(500,dtype='float32, (50000,2)float32')
```

This array is filled with values that I acquire from some measurements, and is supposed to reflect that during each time point (room for 500 time points) we can acquire 50.000 x- and y- coords.

Later in my code is use a `bisect`-like search for which I need to know howmany X-coords (measurement points) are actually in my array which I originally did with `np.count_nonzero(data)`, this yielded the following problem:

```
Fake data:

1 1
2 2
3 0
4 4
5 0
6 6
7 7
8 8
9 9
10 10
```

the non zero count returns 18 values here, the code then goes into the `bisect`-like search using `data[time][1][0][0]` as min X-coord and `data[time][1][(np.count_nonzero(data)][0]` as max x-coord which results in the array stopping at 9 instead of 10.

I could use a while loop to manually count non-zero values (in the X-coord column) in the array but that would be silly, I assume that there is some builtin numpy functionality for this. My question is then what builtin functionality or modification of my `np.count_nonzero(data)` I need since the documentation doesn't offer much information in that regards ([link](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html) to numpy doc).

-- Simplified question --

Can I use **Numpy** functionality to count the non-zero values for a singular column only? (i.e. between `data[time][1][0][0]` and `data[time][1][max][0]` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a better approach would be to filter the array using [`nonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) and iterate over the result:

```
nonZeroData = data[np.nonzero(data[time][1])]
```

To count zeros only from the second column:

```
nonZeroYCount = np.count_nonzero(data[time][1][:, 1])
```

Comment: Wouldn't that yield exactly the same problem and skip all Y-coords which are 0?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your problem. `nonzero`'s purpose is to skip `0` elements - isn't this what you wanted? If you condition is more elaborate you can use [where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy.where).

Comment: I need to retain all datapoints where the X-coord has a normal value but the Y-coord is 0. The approach that I used (and I think this applies to the one you suggest as well) would then skip the empty Y-coord, while I need the number of non-zero X-coords. (so those in `data[time][1][0:unknown][0]`)

Comment: The second part of your answer c(sh)ould be what I was looking for indeed, going to try it for a bit.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, to select elements from `data[time][1][0][0]` to `data[time][1][max][0]`:

```
data[time][1][:max+1,0]
```

**EDIT**:

To count all non-zero for every time:

```
(data["f1"][:,:,0] != 0).sum(1)
```

Comment: If I get OP right, no need to `max+1`, `np.count_nonzero(data[time][1][:,0])` is what he wants

Comment: @alko You are correct, I ended up using BartoszKP's answer with that modification.

Comment: @BasJansen, I added a method that may count all non-zero for every time without for loop. Does this works for you?

Answer (score 0):

Why not consider using `data != 0` to get the `bool` matrix?

You can use:

`stat = sum(data != 0)` to count the non-zero entries.

I am not sure what shape your `data` array has but hope you can see what I mean. :)

Comment: the question was how not to do what you are suggesting, since this would lead to exactly the same problem. I also wished to remain within the numpy library if possible since it has to count a numpy array.